# Appending values of list with set condition

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how I can append the values in `f_list` given that it must satisfy the conditions:

1. The difference between the value in `f_list` and the previous value is greater than `g`.
2. The difference between the value in `f_list` and the value after is also greater than `g`.

This is the code I have established so far:

```
def func (f_list, g): 
    newlist = []
    v = [f_list[i+1]-f_list[i] for i in range(len(f_list)-1)]
    m = [f_list[i-1]-f_list[i] for i in range(len(f_list))]
    for x in f_list: 
        for y in v:
            for z in m:
                if y > g and x>g:
                    new_list.append(x)
    return newlist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readability is sometimes better than terseness

```
# cannot be first or last element
for i in range(1,len(my_list)-1):
    left_diff = my_list[i] - my_list[i-1] 
    right_diff = my_list[i] - my_list[i+1]
    if left_diff > g and right_diff > g:
       new_list.append(my_list[i])
```

I guess it sounds like you want absolute difference, not just difference

```
if abs(left_diff) > g and abs(right_diff) > g:
    ...
```

Comment: This fails one of my cases where `my_list = [ 7, 9, 14, 10, 8, 16, 11, 18 ]` and `g=3`. Your answer outputs `[14, 16]` instead of the expected output which is `[14, 16, 11]`.

Comment: 11-16 is not > 3 ... i guess you need absolute difference (updated answer... although you should have included that bit)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `zip`:

```
from numpy import nan
l = [7, 9, 14, 10, 8, 16, 11, 18 ]
g = 3

[y for x,y,z in zip([nan]+l[:-1],l,l[1:]+[nan]) if (abs(y-x) > g) and (abs(y-z) > g)]

Out[23]: [14, 16, 11]
```